# multiLine option not working in Spark 3.0.0-preview2 using Java

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am getting corrupt record output while using `multiLine` option for JSON file.
This is how I import files:

```
Dataset<Row> df2 = sparksession.read().option("multiLine", "true").json("C:/MyProject/Files/multiline.json");

Dataset<Row> df2 = sparksession.read().option("multiLine", true).json("C:/MyProject/Files/multiline.json");
```

Below there is the json used:

```
    [{
        "id": "1233",
        "Key": "123456",
        "geo_location": {
          "type": "ABC",
          "coordinates": [
            -45.00,
            36.00
          ]
        },
        "properties": {
          "no": "11111",
          "lat_and_lon": [
            36.00,
            -45.00
          ],
          "address": "W South St",
          "year": "2014"
        },
        "timestamp": "2014-03-21T12:28:00-05:00"
      }]

Output:
---------------------
|      _corrupt_record|
---------------------
|                   [{|
|        "id": "1233",|
|     "Key": "123456",|
|    "geo_location": {|
|       "type": "ABC",|
---------------------
```

Comment: Try to import a lower version of Spark. The issue could be a bug of the `3.0.0-preview2` release.